# Using Variables to call a table and columns in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a problem which seems simple in a logical way but not in a sql way

I have a program which allows the user to select a single radio button, the checkChange event sends the text string of the button to a function that compares it to a database which returns the name of the column heading and the name of the table the column comes from as a keyValuePair. simple so far.

There are 8 tables and each table has between 10 and 21 possible choices and each choice is a separate column in one of the tables.

What I am trying to do is call a table using a string variable as the table name, named in the keyValuePair.value and then select all the data from the column named by the keyValuePair.key.
if that makes sense.

Edited.

There is a class of static methods which initialises the data context and gets the tables, each method name is composed of "get" + TableName + "Table()", so we have for example getDescriptionsTable(), this class is called Initialise. getTableValues() returns a KeyValuePair.

```
    KeyValuePair<string, string> names = new getTableValues();
    string colHead = names.Key; // contains the column heading
    string tabName = name.Value; // contains the Table name

    string tableName = "get" + tabName + "Table()" // produce a getTable name

    MyDataContext mdc = Initialise.tableName; // Initialise is a class for getting tables.
                                              // table name is the concat variable above
    var p = from x in mdc.tableName  // here I want to use the variable tableName
            where !x.colHead.equals( null) &&  // here I want to use the variable colHead
                  !x.colHead.contains("")      //  "   "  "    "  "   "    "         "

            select new { Code = x.code,  Property = Convert.ToDecimal(x.colHead) };
    var y = from output in p
            orderby y.Code descending
            select new { Code = y.Code, Property = y.Property};

    DataGridView1.DataSource = y;

    class Initialise
    {
      #region Full Table

      public static System.Data.Linq.Table<Login> GetLoginDetails()
      {
          DataClasses2DataContext log = new DataClasses2DataContext();
          return log.GetTable<Login>();
      }

      public static System.Data.Linq.Table<Descriptions> GetDescriptionsTable()
      {
          DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
          return dc.GetTable<Descriptions>();
      }

      public static System.Data.Linq.Table<Singles> GetSingleTable()
      {
          DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
          return dc.GetTable<Singles>();
      }

      public static System.Data.Linq.Table<Doubles> GetDoubleTable()
      {
          DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
          return dc.GetTable<Doubles>();
      }
      #endregion
    }
```

at this point I have not implemented the join on the second table. That can come later when I understand this problem more fully.

I suppose the SQL equivalent would be
        select @colName from @tableName
        where @colName == NotNull
        and @colName != ""
        order by @colName desc

I am new to Linq to SQL and there may be a simpler way of doing this. But it may not be possible at all. It would mean a lot of if else statements.

Comment: Hello, finding it slightly hard to work out what you want. Is the code above working for you? Do you need help with the next step of this once you have added the items to the listbox?

Comment: As above, I'm having difficulty visualizing this.  Please post a few sample rows from one of the target tables to help out.

Comment: what you try check here `tn.*colHead*.ToString() > 0`?

Comment: What I want is to call a table using a variable such as select * from aVariable.

Comment: Or better still select d.colHead, p.name, p.code
from dbo.tableName d, join dbo.descriptions p on 
d.code == p.descCode
where Convert.ToInt32(d.colHead) > 0;

ColHead and tableName are both variables

Comment: @nigs so possibly you need use `reflection` [Type.GetProperties Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Type.GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y4s51k3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy looking at the code above , I realise it is a total mess and doesn't explain or show what I'm really trying to do.
I will edit the code if I can and break it down into smaller questions.

Comment: @Grundy I think I need to do some more reading into reflection.

Comment: with second part (LINQ query) possibly help [DynamicLinq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) it provide exteinsion for `IQueriable` where you can pass string instead of function

Comment: @nigs can you provide what return `getDescriptionsTable()`?

Comment: @Grundy getDescriptionsTable() is not used in the above code although it exists as a table of 3 columns, int-Code, string-Name, sting-DOB.
This is the next stage where I join the Description Table to the above code.

Comment: @nigs i'm don't quite understand what do `Initialise` and why it return datacontext instead of something like `IQueryable<T>`. Can you clarify it?

Comment: @Grundy, Initialise is a class of static methods such as :
public static System.Data.Linq.Table<Descriptions> GetDecriptionsTable()
      {
         DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
         return dc.GetTable<Descriptions>();
      }

Comment: @nigs add it in post pls

Comment: @Grundy, How do you enter files here?

Comment: @Grundy, I have edited the code section and added the class there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tried several ways and simplest, as i think, will be this

1) add in project reference to [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/), available from NuGet

2) Change your code like this

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> names = new getTableValues();
string colHead = names.Key; // contains the column heading
string tabName = name.Value; // contains the Table name

string tableName = "get" + tabName + "Table()" // produce a getTable name

var table = typeof(Initialise).GetMethod(tableName).Invoke(null, null); // Initialise is a class for getting tables.

var data = ((IQueryable)table).Where(string.Format("!{0}.Equals(@0) && !{0}.Equals(@1)", colHead), null, "")
                              .OrderBy("code")
                              .Select(string.Format("new(code as Code,Convert.ToDecimal({0}) as Property )",colHead));

DataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```